# Testing routes with host constraints via assert_routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, routes, ruby-on-rails-3, testunit

I have a route which I'm using constraints to check the host and then a route which is essentially the same but without the host restriction (these are really namespaces but to make things simple this example will do):

```
 match "/(:page_key)" => "namespace_one/pages#show", :constraints => proc {|env| env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'test.mysite.local' }

 match "/(:page_key)" => "namespace_two/pages#show"
```

These work exactly as expected when accessing via the browser and in integration tests when defining the host and doing `get "/page_key"` etc.

However I want to write tests that ensures that these routes work so far I'm not having much luck as the following test (which is currently in an `ActionController::IntegrationTest` so I can set the host) is matching the one without the constraint:

```
assert_routing '', { :controller => 'namespace_one/pages', :action => 'show' }
=> The recognized options <{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"frontend/pages"}> 
   did not match <{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"namespace_two/pages"}>, 
   difference: <{"controller"=>"namespace_one/pages"}>
```

If I try dumping the env in the constraints proc all I get is `--- :controller`.

If I get rid of the assert_routing and just do a `get :show` call and dump the `@controller` it does resolve to the correct controller (as expected as these routes all work fine via HTTP requests).

Answer (score 7):

Just had this problem myself. This was fixed by a Rails patch that allows you to specify full urls in routing tests.

Change your test to

```
assert_routing 'http://test.mysite.local', { :controller => 'namespace_one/pages', 
                                             :action => 'show' }
```

and it will work fine.

You have to include "://" in the full url b/c rails uses a regex to look for %r{://} in the path or it will automatically hack off the host portion of the url, and the test will error out.